# Add text between tags with TagBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use TagBuilder to return the following string: `<h2>This is my Title</h2>`

Here's what I've got so far:

`var tb = new TagBuilder("h2");
            tb. ??How to add text to go in between??
            var ret = tb.ToString();`

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your class as follows

```
public static class HeaderTagBuilder
    {
        public static string Header2(this HtmlHelper helper, string text, string id)
        {
            return Header2(helper, text,id, null);
        }

        public static string Header2(this HtmlHelper helper,string text, string id = null, object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            // Create tag builder
            var builder = new TagBuilder("h2");
            //add the text
            if (text == null)
                text = string.Empty;//just create an empty string

            builder.SetInnerText(text);

            // Create valid id
            builder.GenerateId(id);

            // Add attributes
            builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

            // Render tag
            return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        }
```

What you where missing is the line

> builder.SetInnerText(text);

Comment: Thanks - this is correct - though I should have mentioned that I am using .Net Core 2.1 and I don't think .`SetInnterText` exists.  I think what I need to do is figure out how to do this with a 'TagHelper`?

Answer (score 0):

It took me a little while to find this but here is the 'current' answer.
You can access the raw HTML of the label element and append to it.
Take care though, keep it simple and use the higher level functions where you can.

```
tb.InnerHtml.Append("This is my Title");
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include a short explanation of *how* this line of code answers the question. This helps to provide context, and makes your answer much more useful for future readers.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt [Hoppeduppeanut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2605758/hoppeduppeanut). I had time to fix this and given it is an effective (and simpler) replacement answer now that SetInnerText isn't available, I could see the necessity.